# How do I show sorting fields to users when the view is added as block?

Tags: views

I have a view that shows a list of *Article* nodes which can be sorted where the sorting fields are exposed to users. When the view is shown as page, the sorting fields are rendered, but when the view is shown as block, the sorting fields aren't rendered.

How do I show sorting fields to users when the view is added as block?

Comment: Guessing you need to enable ajax for the display. It's in the advanced column of the view edit screen.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I just enabled it but it has no effect. Nothing happens on the page as well. I am running `v8.x`.

Comment: Interestingly it works for `v.8.9.8`. Please add it as an answer, I will accept it.